# Qt QGgraphicsView Fix ram usage

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QGraphicsView to load images using this statement:

```
if (QFile().exists(pl)){
    Sleft = new QGraphicsScene;
    Sleft->addPixmap(pl);
    ui->left->setScene(Sleft);
    ui->left->show();
    ui->left->update();
}
if (QFile().exists(pr) && (pr != "")){
    Sright = new QGraphicsScene;
    Sright->addPixmap(pr);
    ui->right->setScene(Sright);
    ui->right->show();
    ui->right->update();
}
else {
    scene3 = new QGraphicsScene;
    ui->right->setScene(scene3);
    ui->right->show();
}
```

Sleft, Sright and scene3 are declared as

```
QGraphicsScene* Sleft;
QGraphicsScene* Sright;
QGraphicsScene* scene3;
```

I'm trying to figure out why the RAM usage keeps increasing and how to solve it. I think it might have something to do with me reinitalizing the variable every time the method is called.

Comment: Do you create a new QGraphicsScene every time you want to load the image?

Comment: I think it does. Scenes are declared everytime the function is called. I couldn't get scenes to behave as global variables...

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to make QGraphicsScenes on the heap? I thought that type was a wrapper around a smart pointer.  Regardless you never delete any of your QGraphicsScenes. When I was doing QT development I don't remember having to delete QT types, they were usually managed for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create a new `QGraphicsScene` and a new pixmap item every time you load an image, but you don't destroy the old scene and the old pixmap item.

It's not necessary to create a new scene every time you load an image. You can create and set one `QGraphicsScene` for each `QGraphicsView` at startup.

When you want to load a new image, you can use `QGraphicsScene::addPixmap` and save the returned `QGraphicsPixmapItem` pointer into a class variable. If an image is already loaded, you must first destoy it using `delete`.

I suggest you to learn more about memory allocation in C++

Comment: I tried to do this before, except because I couldn't get it behave by being declared as a global variable, the QGraphicsView would go blank. I had tried  `delete Sleft` but because it would be declared within the function, it couldn't be accessed outside.

Comment: Sorry but I can't undestand, maybe you can post more code. However you can declare the variables (e.g. the two scenes pointers and the items pointers) as class variables

Comment: Basically I need to load an image into a qgraphicsview which is then deleted when another function is called so I can load another image. If the scene object isn't deleted it creates a memory leak.